# How to Handle Mariadb Downtime Due to Memory Spikes on Server?

Tags: memory-management, server, mariadb, downtime

I am experiencing an issue with my [vgo website](https://www.vgopromo.com) where MariaDB crashes following a memory spike, which results in the website going offline.
I'm looking for a way to automatically restart MariaDB when this happens to minimize downtime until I can address the root cause of the memory issue.

memory spikes turns off mariadb need a fix for this

Comment: So the memory spikes are causes by non-MariaDB causes or MariaDB? How much memory do you have. What measurements/configurations have you made to ensure that there is sufficient memory available? What events correspond to memory spikes?

Comment: spike in php-fpm processes

Comment: limit the number of php-fpm process to what the server can handle. Also are the php processes executing a slow query and that's why there's so many of them?